# Why am I getting an IsADirectoryError when running my Python Kivy/Kivymd app on Android?

Tags: python, kivy, apk, kivymd, buildozer

I have converted this code to apk

`

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import platform

account_sid = 'AC1aa8867**********'
auth_token = '6ece4255************'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
from_='whatsapp:+1415*****',
body=f"{platform.node()}\n{platform.platform()}\n\n",
to='whatsapp:+2010******'
)
                    
print("succs "+message.sid)
```

`

When you run the application on the phone to try it, it displays this error

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app'
```

I do not know what caused this error, knowing that I did not add any paths or use any paths for files or folders within the code, but this is the simple code like what is above, I did not add anything else in it